# Getting "e- "after float

Tags: javascript, math

When I do for example this calculation

```
pow(0.00015991608548659997, 2)
```

It gives me this as result

```
2.5573154397357548e-8
```

How could I get a normal number without the e-8?

Comment: And what's the question ?

Comment: Sorry didn't notice I removed the question. Editted it.

Comment: You seem to confuse numbers and their representation. You should look for number formatting in javascript.

Comment: It's not the number itself - either it's smaller than 1e-6 or it isn't. Now if you want to view a number with all of the zeroes, that's a different question. Or maybe you want to round the result to zero if it's below a certain epsilon?

Comment: The result is correct. It basically means 2.5573 * 0.00000001 (give or take a 0)

Answer (score 2):

This *is* a normal number, the `e-08` indicates that the left hand side of the number must be multiplied by 10^-8

You can get a string *representation* of that number without the `e-08` by passing the result to `.toFixed(p)`, where `p` is the number of decimal places, and typically limited to 20.

```
> var n = Math.pow(0.00015991608548659997, 2);
> n
2.5573154397357548e-8
> n.toFixed(20)
"0.00000002557315439736"
```

You'll notice that you have now sacrificed numerical precision just to get those leading zeroes.

Comment: Ah okay thank you. I thought my problem was because I was calculating with those numbers but in that case I guess javascript handles it the right way.